# Rfacebook: Connection Errow with a R crash

Tags: r

I ran
fb_oauth <- fbOAuth(app_id="XXXXX", app_secret="XXXXXX",extended_permissions = TRUE)
from RFacebook. I had added http/:1410 in siteurl and saved changes.

I waited for a  few minutes and hit enter. A chrome page opened and asked if my app was allowed to access my information. I clicked on ok. But then the page as well as R console closed. The message from  webpage was "Google Chrome's connection attempt to localhost was rejected"